# how to pass data to php via post method from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass data from a hidden iframe to php . I have seen many tutorials for sending data from iframe . But all of those are via get method. I am using one of them (via get method) , below is the code.

```
 function downloadURL(url) {
                    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
                        iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
                    if (iframe === null) {
                        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
                        iframe.style.display = 'visible';
                        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                    }
                    iframe.src = url;
                }
```

But recently I have tried to pass some big amount of data . Then all are not are passing . So I am wanting to pass data via post method using iframe.

Please suggest me how to do that .

Comment: When you say "pass data from iframe to php", you mean from iframe to it's parent frame or another php script ?

Comment: I have wanted to mean that , I want to pass data from iframe to another php script

Comment: For that, you can use `ajax`.

Comment: but , I am trying to force download a file via ajax call with this method. As far I have known by reading tutorials over internet that , its not possible to force download a file via ajax . So everyone is suggesting to add this trick with ajax. So what can I do now?

Comment: Just a moment, why you need to send data from iframe to another php script ? because the iframe will just download a file.